# Anime with a woman in a skimpy, futuristic suit?

Tags: platinumhugen-ordian

Please help find the anime in [this AMV](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xwyvwk_unbelievable-anime-boobs_redband) at 0:33-0:37.

For the sake of convenience, below is a screenshot of the scene

[image: NSFW be ware when clicking it]

Comment: looks like Platinumhugen Ordian. I'll try to verify the episode before I answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After doing a Google image search I found that the gif comes from **Platinumhugen Ordian episode one** at about 4:55. If you were going for the fanservice, you might be disappointed as I hadn't seen much other scenes like these, while scrolling through the series.

[image]

## Synopsis

> Kananase Yu is just an ordinary high-school student. Since he has mysterious inside knowledge about piloting a mecha, he is recruited by the International Military Organization as a potential test pilot for a new mobile armor. However, apparently there are other young recruits around his age, including one of his classmates, were recruited as test pilot as well. Now Kananase Yu must prove that he is the best to be the test pilot.

---

[MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/anime/832/Ginsoukikou_Ordian)
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platinumhugen_Ordian)

Comment: No not for the fanservice they are other anime for that but thanks for finding it.

Comment: my bad new to the site.

Comment: @fatboy Welcome to Anime SE. You can go through the [introductory tour](http://anime.stackexchange.com/tour) to get to know the site and once you earned enough [reputation](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you can join us in the [chat](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). Have fun on the site.